# Bind Vuejs select boxes to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm making a Vuejs form with some select boxes. I have been able to successfully post them through a form into my Rails app. However, when I go and edit the same object, the correct select boxes are not being pre-selected.

For example, if I check:

```
  Item 1
X Item 2
  Item 3
X Item 4
```

submitting the form stores `Item 2` and `Item 4` in the database. But when I edit the form again, vue shows the following as being selected:

```
X Item 1
X Item 2
  Item 3
  Item 4
```

This is because the binding is not working as intended (I think it's binding by index value as opposed to the value of the actual array element's text). I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this glitch though.

Looking at the Vue.js console in Chrome, I can see that `checkedAmenities` is an array with `['Item 2', 'Item 4']` but this is not being properly reflected in the template.

Here is my code:

```
<div v-for="(amenity, idx) in amenities">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-model="checkedAmenities[idx]" :value="amenity.id">
    <span class="custom-control-description">{{ amenity.text }}</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

and my Vue:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('input[name="authenticity_token"]').getAttribute('value');
var listingForm = document.getElementById('listing_form');
var listing = JSON.parse(listingForm.dataset.listing);

const listingForm = new Vue({
  el: '#listing-multistep',
  data: {
    amenities: [
      {id: 0, text: "Item1"},
      {id: 1, text: "Item2"},
      {id: 2, text: "Item3"},
      {id: 3, text: "Item4"}
    ],
    checkedAmenities: listing.amenities
  }
})
```

How can I correctly bind the values stored in checkedAmenities to the form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by re-initializing the values of `checkedAmenities` on mount:

```
mounted: function() {
  var newArray = []
  for(var i = 0; i < this.amenities.length; i++){
    if(this.checkedAmenities.includes(this.amenities[i].text)) {
      newArray.push(true)
    } else {
      newArray.push(false)
    }
  }
  this.checkedAmenities = newArray
}
```

Seems to do the trick